# Prepopulating a textarea element with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to write a program that reads a file and outputs it to the textarea. The user can then edit the file and then click the submit button in order to submit the changes.

Currently, I have a method of obtaining the user's input (request.form), however I do not know how to prepopulate the text area element.

**Flask**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    return 'You entered: {}'.format(request.form['whitelist'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=True)
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color: blue">Index</h1>
  <p>This is an HTML file served up by Flask</p>
  <p>Whitelist:</p>
  <form action="{{ url_for('submit') }}" method="post">
<textarea id="whitelist" name="whitelist" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

      <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So is their a method that exists such that one can prepopulate the textarea?

Example

```
my_file_data = read_my_file(file)
Flask.output(element_id = "whitelist", input = my_file_data)
```

**Implementing Solution**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes in your code (i assume that your file is a .txt but it can work with other file types with some changes):

**Flask**

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    with open('your_file') as f:
        t=f.read()
    return render_template("index.html", t=t)
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="whitelist" name="whitelist" rows="4" cols="50"> {{t}} </textarea>
```

Comment: Implementing your solution results in two blank characters being placed into the textarea. I used a whitelist.txt file with the word "test" in it. I edited the question to show what I'm doing.

Comment: Your route is not correct in the implemented solution. You only use POST method for url '\' You would better separate the 2 routes (use another route to return on submission, to avoid confusion eg '\sub') or add GT method

Comment: The code gives the error t used before it is assigned.